# Using jersey.media.sse with proguard in Android

Tags: android, glassfish, proguard, server-sent-events, jersey-client

Has anybody tried using the Server-Sent Events client from `org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-sse:2.22.1`on Android while proguard is enabled?

For some reason it doesn't get past:

`Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .register(SseFeature.class).build();`

without giving any errors or warnings.

Right now I've tried setting the following proguard rules to no avail:

`-keep class org.glassfish.jersey.media.** {*;}
-keep class javax.** {*;}`

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out by trying different stuff. The following is the rules I used:

```
-dontwarn org.glassfish.***
-keep class org.glassfish.** {*;}
-keep interface org.glassfish.** {*;}
-keep class * implements org.glassfish.** {*;}
-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep class javax.** {*;}
-keep interface javax.** {*;}
-keep class * implements javax.** {*;}
-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-dontoptimize
```

mind you, I have other rules for proguard as well that may contribute to the situation without me knowing, but these are the changes that I had to make to get it working :)